# QGIS attibute form with value relation avoiding table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, values

Is it possible to use some expression or text containing a values list for the dropdown control to display them?

The goal is to use a short list of values and not have to create a related table for the Dropdown control works.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can use the widget **Value Map** : "A combo box with predefined items. The value is stored in the attribute, the description is shown in the combo box. You can define values manually or load them from a layer or a CSV file".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Value Map** widget from the **Widget Type** dropdown in the Attributes Form:

[image]

You can set separate Values and Descriptions, or you can set the Descriptions to be the same as the Values if you just want to see the Values in the dropdown:

[image]